# How to set text length in button

Tags: android, button

I want to have a fixed size button

If the text is longer than button width , it should show "tex..."

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ellipsize can be used but there is a bug. The workaround is to set scrollHorizontally to true and lines to 1. See the following code example:

```
<Button android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
    android:lines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end">
</Button>
```

Comment: Confirm the bug. And confirm this solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code in button

```
android:maxLength="5"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `aString.length();` and if it is greater than whatever int you choose, shorten it with `aString = aString.substring(0, aString.length() - int);` and make that int aString.length() - the max length you want. then take the new string and append the ... with aString.append("...");

Answer (score 0):

Use a textview instead of a button and use the [ellipsize property](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize) to get the 3 dots. Also you will need to have a click listener on the textview to make it function as a button.

You will also need to use : android:scrollHorizontally="true" for the "..." to appear ( bug in android :-( )